# how to delete row in zend framework query?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, delete-row

i need to do a deleting query with limit in zend framework 1

here is my mysql query

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1
WHERE USER =  '123'
LIMIT 1
```

this is my zend query

```
$this->_dbObj->delete('table1', "USER = ?" , 123, "LIMIT ?",1);
```

but this query seems didn't work.
can anybody help? thanks

Comment: Please post error/warning/log if any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your current delete query does not make much sense, because you are using `LIMIT 1` without an `ORDER BY` clause.  You should ideally tell MySQL *which* of the possible matching records you want to delete:

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1
WHERE USER = '123'
ORDER BY some_col
LIMIT 1
```

You may try using `quoteInto` here:

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE USER = ? ORDER BY some_col LIMIT 1";
$query = $this->_dbObj->quoteInto($sql, 123);
$this->_dbObj->query($query);
```